# Classpath option of an external package differs for compiling and running a Java file

Tags: java

I put an external package, the ACM package,  in jdk\jre\lib\ext. By doing this, I don't need to specify the classpath when compiling the file, so `javac Test.java` compiles the file correctly. However, when I want to run the compiled file using `java Test`, I get an error saying "could not find or load main class Test". What is wrong?

The content of Test.java is as follows:

```
import acm.program.*;

public class Test extends ConsoleProgram{
    public void run(){
        println(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have package in Test.java?

Comment: did the class file generated ?

Comment: You should not be putting anything in that directory.  Learn how to set CLASSPATH appropriately.

Comment: No, @Karthikeyan Vaithilingam . I used the acm package.

Comment: @Hiru Yes, the class file was generated.

Comment: share the code of `Test.java`. That will help to know the package declaration of class and other dependencies

Comment: @Mahendra I've added the content of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include acm.jar while compiling and running your program.

example:

```
javac -cp acm.jar Test.java

// on windows
java -cp .;acm.jar Test

// on linux
java -cp .:acm.jar Test
```

Comment: The file compiles correctly without the -cp command, but the compiled file fails to run

Comment: Did you tried to run as I suggested (with jar in classpath)?